# Stripe Gateway Card Payment with Separate Card Elements

Tags: stripe-payments

I am integrating Stripe Gateway with a larval app using vue. I managed to do everything but I am now stuck with a peculiar problem.

For the UI stripe says that I can use their 'card' element, that will show a set of card input fields OR I can COMBINE elements like cardNumber, cardCvc etc to have these info input separately by the user.

When I process the payment using stripe.js confirmPayment API, in all documentations it shows 'card' element only. If I use the api using card element, it works perfectly.

But I want to do the confirmPayment action using cardNumber, cardExpiry and cardCvc.

How can I do that? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Unfortunately stripe's own documentation is silent on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with separate Elements, you can actually pass any of the inputs to the card parameter of [`confirmCardPayment`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment). This is vaguely referenced [here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-with_element-payment_method-card).

> Uses the provided card **or cardNumber** Element for confirmation.

Stripe.js will then pass the other associated inputs (such as `cardExpiry` and `cardCvc`) automatically from the hosted Elements instances on the page. There's no need to pass each Element object manually.

Comment: This worked.. this.$stripe.confirmCardPayment(this.clientSecret, {
                        payment_method: {
                            card:this.cardNumber
                        }
                    })